# position:absolute; not sticking element to base of parent's scrollable height

Tags: css, position, positioning, css-position

Can you look at [jsFiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/GM34W/1/) and tell me why my green `<div>` won't stick to the bottom of its parent's scrollable height? I'm sure it's something simple. Thanks in advance!

Comment: who is the parent? The body tag?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the answer to my comment is yes, than give you body tag a position of relative

```
body
{
position: relative;
}
```

If some  other element is the parent, just replace body with that element. With you given code, the green div is not sticking to the bottom because it is absolutely positioned and does not have any relative or absollutely positioned parent/ancestor, in which case it will position itself relative to the viewport/browser window/canvas (not the canvas element in HTML5) which may or maynot be the html or body element depending on the user agent/browser. When you give the body a position of relative, it provides a new positioning context and than the green div will be positioned relative to the body element. In case if the body tag is not the parent, give the position relative to the parent element, which ever that may be.

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/tAv4h/)

Comment: Excellent, Thank you! I thought that `position:absolute;` would be relative to the body element if no other same-aged or younger parent had `position:relative;` I guess not.

Answer (score 2):

You're not specifying any positioning for the wrapper element (body in this case) so your element is positioning to the bottom of the window.Try assign a position different from static to the wrapper element (relative,absolute whatever it's fine and it depends on your needs)

give a look [here](http://jsfiddle.net/twQ35/)

this might [help](http://www.barelyfitz.com/screencast/html-training/css/positioning/) you

hope this help

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
#green{
    position:fixed;
    ...
}
```

Comment: This is not what I wanted. I said scrollable height not window height.